# xmlforest() omits any fields that are null entirely, instead of creating an "empty" element

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, xml, plpgsql

I'm know I can use an empty string, but I don't want to lose the null functionality in the database. In some cases null is appropriate and I can't use empty strings.

Other than a empty string, how can I cause xmlforest() to create the empty elements?

```
tmpint = 0;

    xmlout = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';
    xmlout = xmlout || '<ListOfFoo FooId="' || input_foo_id  ||'">' || chr(13) || chr(10);

    FOR tmptxt IN
        select xmlforest("foo-orange","foo-apple","foo-banana") from "list-of-foo-meta" where "foo-id" = input_foo_id
    LOOP
        xmlout = xmlout || '<Foo FooNum="' || tmpint || '">' || tmptxt || '</Foo>' || chr(13) || chr(10);
    tmpint = tmpint + 1;
    END LOOP;
    xmlout = xmlout || '</ListOfFoo>' || chr(13) || chr(10);

    return xmlout;
```

P.S - I am just beginning to experiment with the XML functions available in PostgreSQL. This procedure creates valid XML I can use straight from the query (nice), and there might be better ways. Any suggestions or insight would be appreciated.